# How to check equality of irrationals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you check that the following is true?

$$\sqrt {74}+ \sqrt {149} = \sqrt {433}$$

As context, I'm trying to solve a textbook problem: determine whether the points (-5, 11), (0,4) and (7,-6) are collinear using the distance formula.

Comment: square both sides?

Comment: $\left( \sqrt {74}+\sqrt {149}\right)^2\sim 433.0095$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that equality is true, then you can square it to get

$$74+149+2\sqrt{11026} = 433$$

and this equality can only be true if $11026$ is a perfect square, which it is not.

If you are not convinced, you can further simplify the equation to $$2\sqrt{11026} = 210$$

and then to $$\sqrt{11026}=105.$$

Squaring this, you get $$11026=11025$$ which is *close*, but not true.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  If you square both sides, you are comparing $74+149+2\sqrt{74}\sqrt{149}$ to $433$.  As $149$ is prime, $74 \cdot 149$ is not a square and the expression is irrational, so cannot equal $433$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another silly way to do it (this is not the preferred way). For $A = (-5, 11)$, $B=(0,4)$ and $C=(7,-6)$ to be on a straight line, the line through $A$ and $B$ must go through $C$.

The line through $A$ and $B$ can be described by
$$\begin{align}
\pmatrix{x \\ y} 
&= \pmatrix{0 \\ 4} + \pmatrix{-5 - 0 \\ 11 - 4}t \\
&= \pmatrix{0 \\ 4} + \pmatrix{-5 \\ 7}t , \quad t\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align}
$$
For $C$ to be on the line you would have to be able to find a value of $t$ such that
$$
\pmatrix{0 \\ 4} + \pmatrix{-5 \\ 7}t = \pmatrix{7 \\ -6}
$$
That is
$$
\begin{align}
-5 t &= 7 \\
4 + 7t &= -6.
\end{align}
$$
Both this set of equations doesn't have a solution since the first equation would give $t = \frac{7}{-5}$ and the second $t = \frac{-10}{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest: compare squares:
$$\sqrt{74}+\sqrt{149}=\sqrt{433}\iff 223+2\sqrt{74\cdot149}=433\iff\sqrt{74\cdot149}=105$$
Now $74 =2\cdot 37$, hence if the l.h.s. were an integer, it would be divisible by $37$, whereas $105$ is not.

Comment: Oh! Yes. One never re-reads oneself enough· Thank you  for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = (-5, 11),\; B = (0,4),\; \text{and}\; C = (7,-6)$

Note that, in the order $A, B, C$, the $x-$coordinates increase and the $y-$coordinates decrease. This suggests that, if the three points are collinear, then $B$ is between $A$ and $C$; This is sometimes written $A-B-C$.

$AB = \sqrt{(-5-0)^2 + (11-4)^2} = \sqrt{74}$

$BC = \sqrt{(0-7)^2 + (4+6)^2} = \sqrt{149}$

$AC = \sqrt{(-5-7)^2+(11+6)^2} = \sqrt{433}$

So $AB + BC = \sqrt{74} + \sqrt{149}$ and  $AC = \sqrt{433}$

Since $74, 149,$ and $433$ are square-free numbers, they do not simplify. Hence
$AB + BC \ne AC$

If you want a bit more proof,

$(AB + BC)^2 = 74 + 149 + 2\sqrt{2\cdot37\cdot149}$, which is an irrational number.

$AC^2 = 433$, which is a rational number.

So $(AB + BC)^2 \ne AC^2$. Hence $AB + BC \ne AC$.